# ruby weird behavior with integer#times and modulo

Tags: ruby

If I run this

```
100.times do |i|
  unless i == 0 || i.modulo(2) == 0
  p "odd number #{i}"
  end
end
```

I only get back odd numbers, which is the way it should work.

if I run this though

```
100.times do |i|
  unless i == 0 || i.modulo(3) == 0
  p "even number #{i}"
  end
end
```

then I get back a mixture of numbers, some of which are even.

Maybe it's me, or 'unless' isn't the best control to use here.  Kind of weird though that one gives me the result I want, the other not.

Comment: Your second loop is going to give you numbers not divisible by 3. Some are even, some are not.

Comment: Why not just use `.even?` and `.odd?` -- what is your question anyway?

Comment: What I'm saying is I can block all the even numbers by using the 2 as an argument to modulo in my block but using 3 (to block odd numbers) is not working.  For instance, using the `modulo(3) == 0` i get numbers like 89, 97,65, etc.  And, yes I'm aware of .odd? and .even?

Comment: Yes, we know what numbers you're getting because the code you wrote is working as expected. What is difficult to ascertain is what you actually *want*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i.modulo(3) == 0` is not a test for odd; it is a is a test of numbers divisible by 3.

Recall the [*definition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)) of even is divisible by two (or `x % 2 == 0`) and odd is `!even`. Therefore only modulo test for even vs odd is mod 2 with a result of 0 or 1.

Example:

```
100.times { |i| 
     p "even number #{i}" unless i % 2==1 # better as if i % 2==0 
     p "odd number #{i}" unless i % 2==0  # better as if i % 2==1
}
```

To keep it straight, you can also use `.even?` and `.odd?`

Comment: Thank you @dawg , that sets me straight.